# Foreach Loop Not working as expected in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

My Lookup activity Output  in ADF have 10 rows. I want to take only the output of first 5 rows dynamically inside foreach loop. So what expression need to put inside my items expression of Foreach Activity.

Comment: Hey, can't you restrict the output of look up activity to top 5 rows? Just an example like select top 5

Comment: @Nandan
I Can check only first row only option in lookup.How can i make it first 5 rows ?

Comment: Hey, can you specify the source of your look up activity? Is it sql database

Comment: @Nandan No I am using a csv file,but my target is an sql database sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#take) function to get the first five items from your collection.  Set this in the **Items** property of the For Each activity:

```
@take(variables('vArray'),5)
```

An example:

[image: ADF with take]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rownumber in dataflow to generate the row numbers
http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2020/10/row-numbers-in-azure-data-factory-data.html?m=1

And then use filter activity to filter top 5 rows

Comment: I cannot use dataflows since our organisation doesnot allows azure ir to run.Can u please suggest anyother ways to filter the arrays inputs

Comment: Hey, the below method is a crude way which I can think somewhat like concat the 1st 5 elements of array with a special separator like concat(lookup[0], '*', lookup[1] etc and use split function based on the special seperator to convert it back to an array

Comment: Thank you But How can i filter the first 5 rows  if the json is an input array of 100 rows